# Error when i am trying to create a zip from 2 files

Tags: java, spring, inputstream

I am trying to combine 2 files in one zip file

**myMainMethod**

```
private void downloadFileByTypeInner(StaticDocument file, String productCode, int productVersion) throws IOException, TechnicalException {
    ExternalContext ec = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) ec.getResponse();
    String distrib = MultinetFrontHelper.getDefaultDitrib();
    String realPath = findRealPath(ec, file.getPath().replace("{DISTRIB}", distrib));
    String downloadName = file.getDownloadFileName() != null ? file.getDownloadFileName() : file.getPath();

    if (file.getAction() == null || file.getAction().trim().isEmpty() || file.getAction().equals("download")) {
        List<java.io.File> l = new ArrayList<>();
        java.io.File f = new java.io.File(realPath);
        l.add(f);
        if(file.getDependOnCodeFiles() != null){
            String[] paths  = file.getDependOnCodeFiles().split(",");
            for (String codefile : paths) {

                StaticDocument file2 = libraryBusinessService.getFileByCodeType(codefile, productCode, productVersion);
                if((file2 != null)) {
                    l.add(new java.io.File(findRealPath(ec, file2.getPath())));
                }
            }
            downloadName = downloadName.substring(0,downloadName.lastIndexOf("."))+".zip";
        }
        InputStream pathStream = DownLoadHelper.getStreamAllFiles(l.toArray(new java.io.File[0]), downloadName);

        if (pathStream != null) {
            if(downloadName.indexOf('/')!=-1) {
                downloadName = downloadName.substring(downloadName.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
            }
            DownLoadHelper.downLoadFile(response, pathStream, downloadName);
        } else {
            logger.error("Le fichier " + realPath + " est introuvable!");
            throw new TechnicalException(CodeError.CODE_ERTEMO0001, null);
        }

    } else if (file.getAction().equals("open")) {
        final FacesContext ctx = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        final ExternalContext extContext = ctx.getExternalContext();
        try {
            extContext.redirect(file.getPath());
        } catch (final IOException ioe) {
            throw new FacesException(ioe);

        }
    }
}
```

**getStreamAllFiles**

```
public static InputStream getStreamAllFiles(final File[] listDoc, String nameZIP) throws IOException {
    InputStream stream = null;
    if (listDoc != null) {
        if (listDoc.length == 1) {
            stream = new  ByteArrayInputStream(FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(listDoc[0]));
        } else if (listDoc.length > 1) {
            try( ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(baos)){

                for (int i = 0; i < listDoc.length; i++) {

                    try(InputStream fis = new  ByteArrayInputStream(FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(listDoc[i]));BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis)){
                        zos.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(listDoc[i].getName()));
                        byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
                        int bytesRead;
                        while ((bytesRead = bis.read(bytes)) != -1) {
                            zos.write(bytes, 0, bytesRead);
                        }
                    }
                }

                zos.closeEntry();

                stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray());
            }
        }
    }
    return stream;
}
```

**downLoadFile**

```
public static void downLoadFile(HttpServletResponse response,InputStream pathStream,String fileName) throws IOException {
    response.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition",
            "attachment;filename=" + fileName);


    ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
    IOUtils.copyLarge(pathStream, out);
    out.flush();
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().responseComplete();
    IOUtils.closeQuietly(pathStream);
    IOUtils.closeQuietly(out);

}
```

I have this error when trying to open the zip file

[image]

Comment: Too much code here. Downloading files and zip files are two independent functionalities. You should try first to check what part is the problem. Then concentrate on this part. See [Separation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume you're trying to make a zip file with multiple files. The issues are in your `getStreamAllFiles` method as you don't close the zip entry after putting the content of the file, and you don't close the `ZipOutputStream` and the end of the loop, so the file loop should look like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < listDoc.length; i++) {

    try(InputStream fis = new  ByteArrayInputStream(FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(listDoc[i]));BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis)){
        zos.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(listDoc[i].getName()));
        byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
        int bytesRead;
        while ((bytesRead = bis.read(bytes)) != -1) {
            zos.write(bytes, 0, bytesRead);
        }
        zos.closeEntry();
    }
}
zos.close();
stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray());
```

i.e. move the `zos.closeEntry()` inside the loop through the files.

Without moving it inside the `listDoc.length` loop, if you have more than one file you will not be closing the ZipEntry properly at the end of each entry. You also need to issue a `close()` on the ZipOutputStream, as otherwise it will not write the end-of-zip directory (which is shown as an error `End-of-central-directory signature not found` if you test the file under a command line tool.

> In addition, I'd move the allocation of the byte buffer *outside* the file loop as you only need to allocate it once, and reuse the same buffer for all the files you're writing.

Comment: oops, forgot the `zos.close()`, which is also needed

Comment: The long and short of it is that you're creating the byte array from the ByteArrayOutputStream before you've closed the ZipOutputStream - i.e. it's incomplete. By closing the ZipOutputStream beforehand, you ensure all the data is in place correctly.